# What's wrong with this 'proof' that probability of being $2$ m away is $1/9$?

Tags: probability, fake-proofs

Suppose there is a chicken (which we will assume to simply be a point), which is encolsed in a circular barn of radius $6$m. At the centre of the barn, there is a well, (which we will also assume to simply be a point). If the chicken was equally likely to be at any point within the barn, what is the probability that the chicken is **exactly** $2$m away from the well? I know it should be *zero*, since this is a continuous distribution.

However, I was wondering, what goes wrong in the following reasoning to obtain an answer which isn't zero. The only way for the chicken to be exactly $2$m away from the well, is if it were confined to a concentric circle of radius $2$m at the well. The length of the circumference can then be thought of as all the possible points the chicken could be at in order to be $2$m away from the well, so that's $2\pi r' = 2\pi(2) = 4\pi$. All the possible points in the barn is simply the area, so that's $\pi r^2 = \pi(6^2) = 36\pi$.

Hence, if we let $X$ be the random variable of how far the chicken is away from the well, then
$$ \mathbb{P}(X = 2) = \dfrac{4\pi}{36\pi} = \dfrac{1}{9}. $$

So to be extra clear:

> Question: What goes wrong in the reasoning above?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: A circle has area zero. To compute the probability that a point is in a region we must compute the area of interest (zero in this case) divided by the total area which is the area of the $6\text{m}$ radius circle. Therefore, the probability that a point will be found on a given circle within the region is zero.

Comment: @JohnDouma I understand this, however, isn't the point of computing an area so that one can obtain all possible points of interest? In this case, we don't need to find an area whatsoever, since we could just find the circumference to obtain all points of interest?

Comment: Also, just saying, a probability shouldn’t have dimensions. Your method gives the probability a dimension of Length/Area=1/Length.

Comment: @insipidintegrator Yep that makes sense, thank you

Comment: @AliasK That is the nature of probability. We see the same thing with a continuum of numbers like the closed interval $[0,1]$. We can ask about the probability of picking a random element from a small region within the interval, e.g. [$\frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{3}$] but the probability of choosing any given element is zero.

Comment: [disappearing] @JohnDouma Yes that's what I said (Our comments crossed while I was making the above remark). Have just reposted it as an answer instead.

Comment: The circle is a line of length $4\pi$ and width $0$ so has an area of $4\pi\cdot0=0$.

Comment: *All the possible points in the barn is simply the area*, no it is not: *All the possible points in the barn is **infinite*** :-)

Comment: Your $\frac{1}{9}$ is meaningful, but it is not a probability.  If $R$ is a random variable the distance of the chicken from the well, then the *probability density* of $R$  is $f_R(r)=\frac{r}{18}$.  Note that $\int_0^6  \frac{r}{18} \,dr =1$.  When $r=2$ you have $f_R(2)=\frac{2}{18}=\frac19$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What went wrong is that you compared a length with an area. It might help to put units in there. The length of the circle is 4$\pi m$ but the area of the circle is 36$\pi m^2$ so when you divide you get
$$
{1\over 9 m},
$$
and the $m^{-1}$ hopefully shows you it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4):

Roughly speaking, the circumference as a subset of a plane has measure zero.

On the other hand, because an arc of the circumference as a subset of the circumference does not have measure zero, if we land on the circumference and every point on it is equally probable, then it is valid to say that the probability of landing on the circumference's top half equals $\dfrac{\pi r}{2\pi r}.$

Answer (score 0):

You could use the continuity of the probability function here. For instance if you let *X* be a continuous r.v. denoting the chicken's radial distance from the well, then $\{ X=2\} \subset E_{n}:= \{|X-2| \leq \frac{1}{n}\}$ for $\forall n \geq 0$ (i.e. it is a subset of the event that the chicken is in a ring of inner radius $2-\frac{1}{n}$ and outer radius $2+\frac{1}{n}$). Note that $E_{n+1} \subset E_{n}$ so that we have a strictly decreasing set of events. Now,

\begin{align}P(X=2) = P(\lim_{n \to \infty} E_{n}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} P(E_{n}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\pi(2/n)}{36\pi} = 0\end{align}

Here the second equality comes from the continuity of the probability function.